# How to find the Maximum and Minimum value of a Row and a Column Separately in a 2D Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, max, min

How to find:

1. Maximum Value in Row of a 2D array in Java.
2. Minimum Value in Row of a 2D array in Java.
3. Maximum Value in Column of a 2D array in Java.
4. Minimum Value in Column of a 2D array in Java.

---

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number of Students : ");
        byte a=input.nextByte();
        System.out.print("Enter Number of Subjects : ");
        byte b=input.nextByte();
        System.out.println();

        byte[][] st=new byte[a][b];

        //Input Marks for Subjects for different Students
        for(byte i=0;i<a;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Subject Marks for Student "+(i+1)+" :- ");
            for(byte x=0;x<b;x++){
                System.out.print("\tEnter Marks % for Subject "+(x+1)+" : ");
                st[i][x]=input.nextByte();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //Find Student Total
        int[] studTotal=new int[a];
        for(byte i=0;i<a;i++){
            for(byte x=0;x<b;x++){
                studTotal[i]=studTotal[i]+st[i][x];
            }
        }

        //Find Student Average
        float[] studAvg=new float[a];
        for(byte i=0;i<a;i++){
            for(byte x=0;x<b;x++){
                studAvg[i]=(float)studTotal[i]/b;
                studAvg[i]=Math.round(studAvg[i]*100)/(float)100;
            }
        }

        //Find Student Grade
        char[] studGrade=new char[a];
        for(byte i=0;i<a;i++){
            if(studAvg[i]>=75){
                studGrade[i]='A';
            }else if(studAvg[i]>=65){
                studGrade[i]='B';
            }else if(studAvg[i]>=55){
                studGrade[i]='C';
            }else if(studAvg[i]>=35){
                studGrade[i]='D';
            }else{
                studGrade[i]='F';
            }
        }

        //Find Student Maximum
        byte[] studMax=new byte[a];
        for(byte i=0;i<a;i++){
        studMax[i]=st[i][0];//<<==Problem-Solved==>>
            for(byte x=0;x<b;x++){
                if(st[i][x]>studMax[i]){
                    studMax[i]=st[i][x];
                }
            }
        }

        //Find Student Minimum
        byte[] studMin=new byte[a];
        for(byte i=0;i<a;i++){
        studMin[i]=st[i][0];//<<==Problem-Solved==>>
            for(byte x=0;x<b;x++){
                if(st[i][x]<studMin[i]){
                    studMin[i]=st[i][x];
                }
            }
        }

        //Display Information in a Table
        for(byte i=0;i<a;i++){
            for(byte x=0;x<b;x++){
                System.out.print(st[i][x]+"\t");
            }
            //Display Student's Total, Average, Grade, Maximum, Minimum
            System.out.print(studTotal[i]);
            System.out.print("\t"+studAvg[i]);
            System.out.print("\t"+studGrade[i]);
            System.out.print("\t"+studMax[i]);
            System.out.print("\t"+studMin[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you ask us to do your homework. Can you please elaborate what have you tried, and what specific problem you're encountering. Finding max/min sounds just as simple as iterating and storing the intermediate max/min value to me

Comment: show some effort for stating what problem you faced while doing this

Comment: Please @gerrytan & sansix , help me on my trouble, this'z an humble request, plz guyz,

Answer (score 2):

Since this sounds a lot like homework, I shall not go into much detail, but this is how I'd do it:

1. I would have arrays, one for the maximum, and one for the minimum value of each row and column.
2. Initialize the arrays which are to store the lowest values with very large positive numbers, and initialize the arrays which are to store the highest values with very large negative numbers.
3. I would traverse all the rows I have and set the values in these arrays with the maximum and minimum values of each row. This can be easily be done using nested loops. The [`Math.max(double a, double b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28double,%20double%29) and [`Math.min(double a, double b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28double,%20double%29) should come in handy.

EDIT: As per your comment, upon a closer inspection it seems that you are using `byte` all over your application. This is not a suitable data type for this kind of problem. I would recommend using `double` and making a change in your way of getting data from the user by using the [`nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) instead of `nextByte()`.

Comment: i don't know those utils and swings, cn. u plz tell me how to do it ref. above code, plz, plz, i would much appreciate u,

Comment: plz tell me y is that?, i'm much considered in memory allocation, that's y i use byte,

Comment: @user2060289: I think that for this case, you do not need to worry about memory consumption, the program seems to be fairly simple, and using `byte` might not make it as readable. Also, using `double` or `float` data structures will make your program closer to a real life scenario. According to [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) the `Byte` holds from -128 to 127. Your program will not work should it be used in a scenario where SAT scores are used, which I believe have a maximum value much larger than 127

Comment: thanks, i found how to do. it

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = { { 2, 1, 4, 5 }, { 3, 9, 8, 43 } };

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        int minInRow = matrix[i][0];
        int maxInRow = matrix[i][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (minInRow > matrix[i][j]) {
                minInRow = matrix[i][j];
            }

            if (maxInRow < matrix[i][j]) {
                maxInRow = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum in row is" + maxInRow);
        System.out.println("Minimum in row is " + minInRow);
        minInRow = matrix[i][0];
        maxInRow = matrix[i][0];
    }

}
```

The above code will find the min and max from the given 2d array only in a row . Try yourselt to write similar code for column.

Comment: tnx, 4 the reply, let me try this, anyway tnx vry much.

Comment: tnx, i tried this out, bt, i've got trouble in applyin' to my code, would furthur appreciate u if u could help me in this, plz

Comment: tnx vry much, problem solved, tnx, unlike others, u help, anyway thank you, i'll try to find out how to find max and min in a row and post it, tnx